# Does Leksah have hlint, hoogle integration?

Tags: plugins, haskell, leksah, hlint

Does leksah support any kind of plugins? Will it? Does it have any plugins built in, such as hlint, hoogle, pl, djinn? If not, is there an easy way to integrate these things?

Comment: `pl` and `unpl` should be refactoring operations. They are so useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does leksah support any kind of plugins?

Current version not.

> Will it?

I am working on a major restructuring, to build Leksah from plugins from the very base.

https://github.com/leksah/billeksah/wiki

Unfortunately this project may take some more time to reach delivery, 
but hope it will pay off.

> Does it have any plugins built in, such as hlint, hoogle, pl, djinn?

It has simple support for lookup of hoogle docs.

> If not, is there an easy way to integrate these things?

Help is very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Well someone ought to answer. Here's my best guesses:

> Does leksah support any kind of plugins?

Nope

> Will it?

It's open source (GPL 2)...get to it! (Doesn't look like this feature is on any roadmap or anything.)

> Does it have any plugins built in?

According to [the manual](http://leksah.org/leksah_manual.pdf) page 32:

> With the Docu button you can initiate an external search in a browser with e.g. Hayoo
>   or Hoogle, depending on the configuration in the Preferences.

That's about all I could find.